# What version of Entity Framework is packaged with .Net Standard 2.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working with a legacy project that targets .Net Standard 2.1.  I'm a little confused because although this project is a data access layer that uses EF extensively, there are no EF nuget packages or references in the project.  So, does .Net Standard 2.1 include an EF implementation?  If so, what version of EF is it?

Here is the content of the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider" Version="3.5.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.5.6.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SimpleEmail" Version="3.5.0.52" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Comment: if the library (`AWSSDK.xyz`) includes ef, then the parent project no need again?

Comment: @LeiYang Yah, I checked that -- those are just Amazon (AWS) libs for working with their API -- no EF references there.  I walked the Packages tree in Solution Explorer to confirm.

Comment: *PackageReference* is one of the nuget format, did you check another one (*package.config*)?

Comment: Yep — no package.config in the folder. I wonder if EF is part of the target platform set — it isn't listed when I expand that node in the dependency tree, but it’s about the only other possibility I see.

Comment: do you have a minimal reproducible project, for us to investigate, in github for example?